What is the universe of a dependent function type in type theory?
What would be the universe of the following type in type theory:
$
(i : \text{Level}) \to (t : \mathcal{U}_i) \to t \to t
$
This should have a proper type because many programming languages based on type theory (like agda and idris) support this type, and this would also be the type of the identity function, but it seems impossible for this type's universe to have an ordinal level!

Note that this question isn't specific to homotopy type theory.

If you wanted this type to live in a universe, you would typically introduce a new universe level $\omega$ higher than every previous level and have it live in $\mathcal{U}_\omega$. That's what Agda does:
open import Agda.Primitive
Id : Setω
Id = (l : Level) → (t : Set l) → t → t

In general you can have universe hierarchies indexed by any ordinal number, or more generally a well-founded order, or even more general things (see An Order-Theoretic Analysis of Universe Polymorphism).

Thank you for your solution, but I should clarify. I was asking about a type where Level represents the type of all ordinals, so that you could for example pass $\omega+1$ as the argument to level, which in your solution isn't possible.

In that case you may want to read section 5.3 in Generalized Universe Hierarchies and First-Class Universe Levels.

Paraphrasing: you can't have universe polymorphism over all levels and still live in a universe, because that universe would need to have a level greater than itself. What you can do (and what Agda does) is limit the internal levels to $\omega$ (there is no Level term representing $\omega$) and extend the hierarchy to $\omega + 1$ or $\omega + \omega$.
